# How to see name of application connected to Informix database?

Tags: jdbc, informix

In JDBC there is:

```
Connection.setClientInfo("ApplicationName", myAppName);
```

Using PostgreSQL I can see `myAppName` via SQL query:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity;
```

Using Informix I hoped to see it in `feprogram` column of `syssessions` table but it is empty. I tried also `onstat` command line utility but I cannot see any session list.

My environment:

Client: Informix JDBC Driver for Informix Dynamic Server 4.50.JC1

Server: IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.50.FC4

How to see name of application connected to Informix database?

Comment: I think you can see the information in later versions than 11.50 (maybe 11.70, probably 12.10, probably 14.10).  You should be aiming to update from 11.50 to at least 12.10 and preferably 14.10.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things to note here.  First is that with Informix 12.10 and 14.10 servers at least, feprogram is populated by the JDBC driver. The JDBC driver looks for server capabilities on whether it submits the feprogram data and 11.50 might be too old for it??

Here is an example of feprogram output using the 4.50.1 JDBC driver with a 14.10 Informix server.

```
[bhughes@ultima ~]$ dbaccess sysmaster -

Database selected.

> select feprogram from syssessions where sid=429;

feprogram  Thread[id:1, name:main, path:/work/jdbc/jdbc-4.50.1.jar]

1 row(s) retrieved.
```

Now for JDBC and the Connection.setClientInfo() APIs. The JDBC spec only requires that the driver support setting/getting client info for any parameters that are returned by [DatabaseMetadata#getClientInfoProperties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getClientInfoProperties()). Informix does not return any values for this as of 4.50.1, so that tells us it will not support setting or retrieving any client info properties from the Connection object at this time.

The "ApplicationName" client info parameter is not a JDBC standard, but rather is a vendor specific parameter that is not supported by all databases.

It would be nice if the Informix JDBC driver did support client info properties, it just does not at this time.

As for CLIENT_LABEL provided by Alexandre you have to have the corresponding 12.10XC10 or higher server for that to work sorry to say.

Answer (score 0):

Informix 12.10.xC10 new features shows:

- Easier Session Tracking
  CSDK: Introduction of new CLIENT_LABEL environment variable which facilitates the clients to tag themselves for monitoring purposes

So your CSDK is ok, since this started on 4.10.xC10.

But I don't know if the engine will recognize it.

```
onstat -g ses
onstat -g env
```

and select on sysmaster can also be used to trace.

Please consider upgrading ASAP.

Comment: CLIENT_LABEL needs the corresponding 12.10.xC10 or higher server to work correctly.  I notice that part is not mentioned in the documentation for CLIENT_LABEL in the knowledge center.